How do I transform a table to automatically turn merged rows into replicating single rows in excel
I have a spreadsheet where there are numerous rows where for the sake of appearance the categories are merged rather than repeated. I want to unmerge them automatically so I can use for lookups and analysis.
The below images show what I'm starting with and what I want to automatically tranform it to.

Can this be done without macros? Power query is fine, I started looking at power query but could not find what to look at.

Here is one way of doing this automatically which will spill the whole data with one single dynamic array:


• Formula used in cell D1
=VSTACK(A1:B1,HSTACK(SCAN(,A2:A6,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),B2:B6))


One could exclude the header in the above formula if not needed then:
=HSTACK(SCAN(,A2:A6,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),B2:B6)


NOTE: All the above formulas works with Modern Versions of Excel aka MS365

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)


To use Power Query follow the steps:

First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as Table1



Next, open a blank query from Data Tab --> Get & Transform Data --> Get Data --> From Other Sources --> Blank Query



The above lets the Power Query window opens, now from Home Tab --> Advanced Editor --> And paste the following M-Code by removing whatever you see, and press Done


let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(Source,{"Category Merged"})
in
    #"Filled Down"



Lastly, to import it back to Excel --> Click on Close & Load or Close & Load To --> The first one which clicked shall create a New Sheet with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.


Another simple way is Convert the range into Structured References aka Tables --> Select any cell in the data and hit CTRL+T, once you do this it automatically unmerges the ranges/cells. Next select the Category Merged Column hit F5 (Function Key) --> Select Special --> Select Blanks --> Press OK --> Next Press = --> Top Arrow and hit CTRL+ENTER together it will fill all the cells below with the above data respectively.


